# Does spring security context persist across REST/SOAP calls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Do Spring security context persist while calling rest/soap services from Client. I have client application which sets authentication using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(). Client application makes rest/soap calls where I have to get context.

```
//Setting security context in client application: 
User contextUser = new User(username, enc_password, true, true, true, true,grantedAuthorities, null);
authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(contextUser, username,grantedAuthorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

// on server side 
// I want to get following authentication on server side to get logged in user
Authentication auth=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    User user= null;
    if (auth != null && !(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        // userDetails = auth.getPrincipal()

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        String username = null;
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
            user = (UserDetails) principal;

        } else {
            username = principal.toString();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Well no. Client and Server are completely seperate. So trying to set it and expect it to be available on the server will not work.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can make/set authentication available on server side?

Comment: Not from the client. Send the username/password and Spring Security will handle it.

Comment: I will pass username, encrypted password from client by adding them in header of rest/soap request and set authentication on server side.

Comment: You don't need to set anything... Spring Security will do all of that for you. Just send them as basic or digest authentication headers and Spring Security will do everything for you. Work with the frameworks you are using, not around them.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest me some tutorial for sending username and password as authentication headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access `username` on server side, after REST/SOAP API calls are made, you can do it by adding username in each request's header, before making API call.

Intercept each request on the server-side by using Spring Interceptors, you can create interceptor class by implementing a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` interface.

[For more information about interceptors.](https://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter)